# DarkaOnline Swagger-php generates incorrect interface

Tags: php, angular, laravel, typescript, swagger

I'm currently using a Swagger php library by: https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger

And in my sample model class is as such:

```
/** @OA\Schema(
 *    title="ProductPromotion",
 *  @OA\Property(property="id", type="integer"),
 * @OA\Property(property="uid", type="string"),
 * @OA\Property(property="store_id", type="integer"),
 * )
 */
class ProductPromotion extends Model
{
..
}
```

Notice that I wrote "store_id" in the 3rd property there. But when I used this jar file:
**openapi-generator-cli-4.1.3**, I get the interface as such:

```
export interface ProductPromotion { 
    id?: number;
    uid?: string;
    storeId?: number;
}
```

The name changes from "store_id" to "storeId". I don't want this, anyone knows how to solve this?

EDIT: The command used to generate:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.1.3.jar generate -i C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\OpenAPICodegen\swagger.json -g typescript-angular -o C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\OpenAPICodegen\dist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to iizno's answer, I've managed to solve it by adding this additional property when generating the typescript code.

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.1.3.jar generate -i C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\OpenAPICodegen\swagger.json -g typescript-angular -o C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\OpenAPICodegen\dist --additional-properties modelPropertyNaming=snake_case
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you :

https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/wiki/FAQ

> TypeScript
>   The JSON response failed to deserialize properly into the object due to change in variable naming (snake_case to camelCase). Is there any way to keep the original naming?
>   Yes, please use the following option when generating TypeScript clients:

```
modelPropertyNaming
    Naming convention for the property: 'camelCase', 'PascalCase', 'snake_case' and 'original', which keeps the original name (Default: camelCase)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but where do I write that exactly?

Comment: Add this :  --additional-properties modelPropertyNaming=snake_case to you cli command.